# In eclipse when I try to create a Servlet by implementing the Servlet interface then the annotation method does not create the correct link on running

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/impSer")
public class impSer implements Servlet {
     private transient ServletConfig config;

        @Override
        public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
            this.config = config;
        }

        @Override
        public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            System.out.println("h");
        }

        @Override
        public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
            return this.config;
        }

        @Override
        public String getServletInfo() {
            return "TheServletInter";
        }
}
```

I have saved my code in the src/main/java folder in the default package in my eclipse project named firstwebsite..
When i run my code on the Tomcat server it generates this url
http://localhost:8080/firstwebsite/WEB-INF/classes/impSer.java
and gives Http Status 404-Not found error..

I have used the annotation method so shouldnt it generate the correct url on running on server i.e. http://localhost:8080/firstwebsite/impSer

When i type this manually it gives correct output.. but eclipse on running does not run the above url..

I have Tomcat 9..

The annotation method is working perfectly for Servlets created by extending GenericServlet and extending HttpServlet.. only the implementing Servlet interface is giving issues..

I am new to Servlet programming so the helpp will be really appreciated.. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with it "generating" the URL?

Comment: @dan1st on eclipse when we press run on server.. it automatically opens the web browzer with the correct url that is used to run the particular servlet we r trying to execute

Comment: What version of Eclipse is it?

Comment: @nitind Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not extending `HttpServlet`?

Comment: @nitind Just trying to learn all the ways to create a servlet

Answer (score 1):

Odd. Sounds similar to [bug 577703](https://bugs.eclipse.org/577703), but I fixed that one. Can you open an issue at https://github.com/eclipse-servertools/servertools/issues and attach this project, or another minimal project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: My project just has the code I have provided above.. in a project folder named firstwebsite and the code is saved in a file named impSer.java in the src/main/java folder of the java project

Comment: Right, but the surrounding metadata files are also of interest.